# SUMs with GROUP WITH ROLLUP - query too slow

Tags: mysql, sql

**My Query** is very slow returning results. It takes more than 30s (depending a lot on the use of the server). The table has some records.

I cannot divide this table for other reasons. I added this to the query `` `TYPE` IN (1,3)' `` and the response time has improved significantly. But it remains very slow.

It is worth mentioning that I have already add an INDEX for the `PRODUCT`, `TYPE`, `STATUS` columns.

**Question:** How can I speed up the query response time **without** having to divide it by many tabs and have to use the `INNER JOIN`?

**Other Useful Information:**

Records: 1,436,004
Record length: 240 Bytes
Records size: 291 Bytes

**My Query:**

```
SELECT `PRODUCT`, 

SUM(DATE_FORMAT(`REG_DATE`,'%m/%Y') = '11/2020' AND `TYPE` = 1) AS `SUMT1_1`, 
SUM(DATE_FORMAT(`REG_DATE`,'%m/%Y') = '12/2020' AND `TYPE` = 1) AS `SUMT1_2`, 
SUM(DATE_FORMAT(`REG_DATE`,'%m/%Y') = '01/2021' AND `TYPE` = 1) AS `SUMT1_3`, 
SUM(DATE_FORMAT(`REG_DATE`,'%m/%Y') = '02/2021' AND `TYPE` = 1) AS `SUMT1_4`, 
SUM(DATE_FORMAT(`REG_DATE`,'%m/%Y') = '03/2021' AND `TYPE` = 1) AS `SUMT1_5`, 
SUM(DATE_FORMAT(`REG_DATE`,'%m/%Y') = '04/2021' AND `TYPE` = 1) AS `SUMT1_6`,

SUM(DATE_FORMAT(`REG_DATE`,'%m/%Y') = '11/2020' AND `TYPE` = 3) AS `SUMT3_1`, 
SUM(DATE_FORMAT(`REG_DATE`,'%m/%Y') = '12/2020' AND `TYPE` = 3) AS `SUMT3_2`, 
SUM(DATE_FORMAT(`REG_DATE`,'%m/%Y') = '01/2021' AND `TYPE` = 3) AS `SUMT3_3`,
SUM(DATE_FORMAT(`REG_DATE`,'%m/%Y') = '02/2021' AND `TYPE` = 3) AS `SUMT3_4`, 
SUM(DATE_FORMAT(`REG_DATE`,'%m/%Y') = '03/2021' AND `TYPE` = 3) AS `SUMT3_5`, 
SUM(DATE_FORMAT(`REG_DATE`,'%m/%Y') = '04/2021' AND `TYPE` = 3) AS `SUMT3_6`

FROM `MY_TABLE` WHERE 

`TYPE` IN (1,3) AND

`STATUS` IN('AVAILABLE','IN PROCESS')

GROUP BY `PRODUCT` ASC 
WITH ROLLUP HAVING (`SUMT1_1`+`SUMT1_2`+`SUMT1_3`+`SUMT1_4`+`SUMT1_5`+`SUMT1_6`+`SUMT3_1`+`SUMT3_2`+`SUMT3_3`+`SUMT3_4`+`SUMT3_5`+`SUMT3_6`) >= 1
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, but there is no problem with the front end, or php code, but with the response time of that query. I am precisely looking for another alternative.

Comment: To my way of thinking, everything above should be resolved in front-end code.

Comment: Group by ```PRODUCT, DATE_FORMAT(REG_DATE,'%m/%Y'), TYPE``` then pivot the result statically. Also add the condition by `REG_DATE BETWEEN '20220-11-01' AND '2021-04-30'`.

Comment: @Strawberry, correct me if I'm wrong, but: sql is more fast than php ... if you can solve the maximum inside the BD, better.

Comment: @Akina, thank you, my query response time goes from the 30s to 3s (average), mainly with ```REG_DATE BETWEEN '20220-11-01' AND '2021-04-30'```, thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 0):

With an index on some combination of (status,type,reg_date), I would write that query this way:

```
SELECT product
     , DATE_FORMAT(reg_date,'%Y-%m') reg_ym
     , type
     , COUNT(*) subtotal
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE type IN (1,3) 
   AND status IN('AVAILABLE','IN PROCESS')
   AND reg_date >= '2020-11-01' 
   AND reg_date < '2020-05-01'
 GROUP 
    BY product 
     , reg_ym
     , type
 ORDER
    BY product
     , reg_ym
     , type
```

...and handle any remaining aspects of the problem in application code

Comment: Or use that as a derived table, and have a CASE expression in the outer query to do the "pivot".

Comment: (*I* didn't say that)

Comment: (I agree that the app is a better place to put it.  But I did not think you deserved a downvote for that.  And your query was the start of a pure-sql answer.)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution was given by @Akina (in the comments), and reduced the response time from 30s to 3s (average).

Adding the condition:

`` `REG_DATE` BETWEEN '20220-11-01' AND '2021-04-30' ``

But to fit better with my php code i prefer to use:

`` DATE_FORMAT(`REG_DATE`,'%m/%Y') IN ('11/2020','12/2020','01/2021','02/2021','03/2021','04/2021') ``